# Rotate span element borders on parent hover

Tags: css, hover, transform

I have 3 horizontal lines within a div. When I hover on the enclosing div, I'd like to rotate the first and last lines to form a `+` (plus sign).

At the moment, when you hover on the first and last lines, they rotate at 90deg but I'd like the lines to rotate when I hover anywhere within the div. I'm not sure if CSS3 alone can do this or if I need to use jQuery.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72y4r4wj/) of the below:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
div .bar {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
div .bar:first-child:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
div .bar:last-child:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the parent div the `:hover` pseudo-class and target its children — `div:hover children`

---

That said, I'm a sucker for a smooth animation; that's what I have concentrated on in this example, along with reducing the markup required.

Let's make this — the middle stroke fades away and the bottom stroke completes a 360 rotation ending up in the middle. The two examples to the right take it a little further. These are low-grade gifs that look a lot better in the demos below!

[image: Example Animations]

#### The HTML

Just one HTML element is required:

```
<div></div>
```

#### The CSS

- The first and third strokes are created with [`:before` and `:after` pseudo elments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
- The middle stroke is created with the [box shadow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) of `:before`. They create the same as this:

  ```
  <div>
    <div>I am :before</div>

    I am an illusion created by box-shadow

    <div>I am :after</div>
  </div>
  ```
- The smooth transition is given by `div:before, div:after { transition: all 0.3s; }`

#### Complete Example - simple transition

```css
div:before,
div:after {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  transform: rotate(0);
}
div:before {
  margin-top: -20px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 0 #FFF;
}
div:after {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div:hover:after {
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
div:hover:before {
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

#### More examples

You can make all kinds of animations with this basic concept:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

div,
div:before,
div:after {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  transform: rotate(0);
}
div:before {
  margin-top: -20px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 0 #FFF;
}
div:after {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div.one:hover:after {
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
div.one:hover:before {
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: rotate(450deg);
  box-shadow: none;
}
div.two:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
div.two:hover:after {
  margin-top: -3px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
div.two:hover:before {
  margin-top: -3px;
  transform: rotate(450deg);
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
div.three {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #F00;
}
div.three:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #F00;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}
div.three:hover:after {
  margin-top: -3px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
div.three:hover:before {
  margin-top: -3px;
  transform: rotate(450deg);
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);  
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #F00;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #F00;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);  
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #F00;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);  
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #F00;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05);  
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #F00;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);  
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #F00;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Spinny</h2>
<div class="one"></div>

<h2>Circular Ripple</h2>
<div class="two"></div>

<h2>Heartbeat</h2>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [box shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top:15px;
    position: relative;
}
div:before, div:after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
     height:8px;
    background: white;
}
div:after{
    display:none;
}
div:before{
    left:10px;
    top:30px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 0 white,0  40px white
}
div:hover:before{
    box-shadow:none;
    top:50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
div:hover:after{
    display:block;
    left:10px;
    top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

if you want to avoid transform and box shadow you can do this

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top:15px;
    position: relative;
}
div:before, div:after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
}
div:after{
    width:80px;
    height:8px;
    background: white;
    top: 50px;
    left:10px;
}
div:before{
    left:10px;
    top:30px;
    width:80px;
    height:34px;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}
div:hover:before{
    border:none;
    height:80px;
    width:8px;
    background:white;
    left:44px;
    top:20px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A rule that matches the first bar in a div when hovered would look like

```
div:hover .bar:first-child
```

not

```
div .bar:first-child:hover
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72y4r4wj/1/)